# Renting a car with automatic transmission in Paris

Tags: budget, france, car-rentals

In France the vast majority of cars have manual transmission. To my knowledge, most of the cars with automatic transmission are luxury cars. Is it possible to rent a car with automatic transmission in Paris at a decent price (e.g. a price close to cheap rental car with manual transmission)? I plan to drive around 1,200 Km around France for vacation over 5 days in early July (~July 2 to July 6), with 7 people including myself, Paris being the start and end points.

Comment: Now someone will come and say "you are not a man unless you drive a manual car"...

Comment: @IKeelYou  "you are not a man unless you ride a horse"! :)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt you drove too much in America, you're taking bad habits :)

Comment: @Vince Some people just prefer the simplicity of an automatic transmission. They're generally easier to drive and don't stall as easy, especially while shifting.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Can they stall at all? Never happened to me…

Comment: @Relaxed I don't drive AT ALL, so I'm not sure.

Comment: Follow-up: [Android or IOS navigation app that gives an alert when close to a speed camera in France](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/19037/903)

Comment: @Relaxed since you asked, automatics very rarely stall, but it is possible, and happens with older cars that are in bad condition. An automatic transmission uses a hydraulic torque converter instead of a clutch, so the biggest cause of stalls in manuals (improper use of the clutch) is eliminated. The clutch isn't the only thing that can cause an engine to stall, though. Circuitry slowly disintegrates, the torque converter can lock up, or the car may simply be out of gas. If the engine can't achieve combustion, it stalls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that any large rental company will have automatic transmission cars. Looking at [Hertz](https://www.hertz.fr/rentacar/reservation/#vehicles/sort/original) cars, you can get a class F car (4-5 passenger compact sedan) with automatic transmission for 450-550`EUR` for a week. A smaller manual car would cost you 300-400`EUR`. Whether this is cheap for you is up to you to decide. See below for a screenshot of a sample booking:

[image: Hertz automatic]

For more options, you can choose "Boite Automatique" as vehicle type when booking:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, in the end I rented a Citroën Grand Picasso from Hertz: 650 euros for 4 days (from July 3 to July 6), automatic transmission, 1000 km included, 0.38 euros per extra km, full insurance included in Paris.

Answer (score 4):

You could get a Smart Fortwo. It probably counts as an entry-level car and has an automated manual transmission, with no clutch pedal (you do need to press a button on the steering wheel to engage the higher gear). Won't seat 7, though ;-)

Small hybrid cars (like the hybrid version of the Toyota Yaris) could also be an option, although I am not sure whether you could easily rent one of those. No gearbox, whether automatic or manual on that one (same for electric cars obviously).

Otherwise, you can ask for a car with automatic transmission from many rental companies (just checked Avis, Hertz and Europcar). The smallest city cars won't have it but it's available starting with the compact car category (VW Golf), so nothing super-luxurious. You would need two of those for your party.

If you all want to be in the same vehicle, you will need a van. I guess you could get one with automatic transmission too but it's going to cost you in any case. Really, if you are travelling with 7 people and want to drive a lot, the price of the cheapest manual transmission cars is moot because you need a bigger car one way or the other.

Comment: I might be mistaken but I think you can not find 7 seat cars in the cheap category. Manual nor automatic transmission. Renting in France is not that cheap to start with, add the price of gas/petrol, tolls, parking fees and insurance for the car, I think you get into the expensive category even when you have the best offer for the car.

Comment: @Willeke Indeed, that's precisely my point ;-)

Comment: This shifting by buttons is so confusing, last time I tried it I felt like I just learned how to drive.